# Eager load a single entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, include, irepository

Using Entity Framework and ASP.NET I can easily eagerload a whole list of entities using `IRepository.GetAll().Include()`.
Is there also an easy and short way to eagerload a single entity, like `IRepository.Get().Include()` ?

For example, I am now writing

`var mi = _miRepository.GetAll().Include(m => m.Type).Where(m => m.Id == input.Id).First();`

while I feel that getting all and then filtering with Where and First is redundant and ugly. It would look so much cleaner like this:

```
var mi = _miRepository.Get().Include(m => m.Type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repository pattern is using something like:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
// and 
TEntity Get(int id);
```

Then you can alter the Get() method to also return `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> Get(int id);
```

where the contents would need to change from something like:

```
return _context.DbSet<TEntity>().Find(id);
```

to:

```
return _context.DbSet<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Id == id);
```

This will mean any existing calls that expected a single entity back will need to be updated from:

```
var entity = repository.Get(id);
```

to:

```
var entity = repository.Get(id).Single();
```

While it may seem counterintuitive to use `IQueryable` for a method that intends to return a single object, this does give callers the flexibility to leverage projection (`.Select()`) as well as have control over what related details you might want to eager load, or simply do an exists check (`.Any()`) without actually loading the entity into memory.

Comment: Right, and then I could even create my own Repository interface inheriting from IRepository, where I add a GetIncluding() method, that returns  `_context.DbSet<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Id == id).Sigle()`;  right, so that I don't have to write `Single()` after every `Get()`.

Comment: It is a rabbit hole. EF offers a lot more than just loading an entity and its related entities. It also handles filtering (`Where`), sorting, pagination, (`Skip`/`Take`) projection (`Select`). You would need more parameters and conditional code (complexity) to handle these. You many also have conditions where you just need to do an Exists check (`Any`) or a `Count`, which means more methods in such an interface that only a fraction of implementations would need. Unless there is a legitimate need for a repository, you are far better off using the repository EF provides, the `DbSet`.

Comment: Right, you mean not using IRepository at all? I think I read that recommendation elsewhere too... However I'm working on a project that I did not start. The IRepository pattern is used everywhere already.

Comment: Then I would consider the change to "Get()" to return `IQueryable` and do a Find Usages to introduce the `.Single()` or consider adding a "GetQueryable()" or "GetQ()" to return the `IQueryable` for an item by ID so you can use that in cases where you want to do eager loading, projection, etc.  If the existing code is using `IQueryable` for the "GetAll()" I'd just bite the bullet and adopt it for "Get()" as well. If the consumer calls can handle #null returns then they would use `SingleOrDefault()`.